# aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources query by LogicalResourceId

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am attempt to retrieve a stack PhysicalResourceId using the aws command line.

```
$ aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources \
      --stack-name test-app-prometheus \
      --query 'StackResources[?LogicalResourceId=="PrometheusAutoScalingGroup"]'
```

I was expecting this to return:

```
[
   {
        "ResourceStatus": "...",
        "LogicalResourceId": "...",
        "StackName": "test-app-prometheus",
        "StackId": "...",
        "PhysicalResourceId": "test-app-prometheus-PrometheusAutoScalingGroup-...",
        "ResourceType": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
        "Timestamp": "2016-11-08T15:17:23.567Z"
   }
]
```

However instead it is returning an empty array.

```
[]
```

Running the command without the query and I can see the resource. Running the command:

```
$ aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources \
    --stack-name test-app-prometheus \
    --query 'StackResources[*].LogicalResourceId' \
 | grep PrometheusAutoScalingGroup
"PrometheusAutoScalingGroup",
```

suggests that the resource exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$ aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources \
      --stack-name test-app-prometheus \
      --logical-resource-id PrometheusAutoScalingGroup
```

[CloudFormation and the New AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/cloudformation-and-the-new-aws-cli/)

Comment: Completely missed that. Thanks.